# Calling Jquery file function from code behind page

Tags: c#, jquery, vb.net

I have got the following function in the Empdocs.js file

$('.resetButton').click(function () {
        $('#searchField').val('');
    });

How can i call this function from code behind page in VB.Net or C#?

I have tried the following function but it is not working.

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "resetfunction", "resetButton();", True)

Comment: i am using asp.net file upload control and want to reset it after i save the record. It works fine if i click on the reset button but i am trying to call it from code behind page so that user doesn't have to click in the reset button.

Answer (score 0):

create Reset - function:

```
function Reset() {
  $('#searchField').val('');
}
$('.resetButton').on("click", Reset);
```

and from server side you can call

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "resetfunction", "Reset();", True)
```